# Get clicked <li> value via PHP script

Tags: php, html, html-lists

How can I get the **clicked** `<li>` tag inside an `ordered list`? For example I have this:

```
<ol>
   <li>Text 1</li>
   <li>Text 2</li>
   <li>Text 3</li>
</ol>
```

When I click on the first `<li>` tag I want to **get it's relative value** using PHP.
Thanks

Comment: You need a form to post data from client to server-side (php). Also, close every list item element with `</li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible in PHP, to achieve that you should post the data.
With JQuery for example it's possible:

To get the value you could try something like this in JQuery:

HTML:

```
<ol id='test'>
   <li>Text 1</li>
   <li>Text 2</li>
   <li>Text 3</li>
</ol>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#test li').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert('Text is ' + text);
});
```

Comment: Yes, with JQuery will also do the trick. Tried that and think this will do just fine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: and with `var index = $(this).index()` I can take the li number

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the clicked value then..

```
<ol>
   <li onclick="window.location.href='page.php?clicked=1'">Text 1</li>
   <li onclick="window.location.href='page.php?clicked=2'">Text 2</li>
   <li onclick="window.location.href='page.php?clicked=3'">Text 3</li>
</ol>

page.php
<?php
echo $_GET["clicked"]; //Or do whatever you want
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. A good solution. Will rate it up.